# ACA application don't display repo constrain property as dropdown

Tags: dropdown, alfresco

I have defined constrain property in repo like this:

[image]

In the ACA application but this property looks like text property without dropdown.

[image]

Is there any way how to show this property as dropdown ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alfresco 7 will include this feature.